# Rendering code using Apache/SVN on Ubuntu

Tags: php, svn, ubuntu, lamp

I'm not sure if I'm missing the point here...

Our devs want the following...

On a LAMP server with SVN/WebDAV they want the root Apache directory to be a repository that they can all work on. However, setting the default Apache directory to a repo doesn't work as the files aren't stored as html/php files, instead in the SVN db structure to handle changes/revisions/etc.

Is there any way to do this? or would we have to have a separate repo that they copy files to/from the web root when developing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup a separate svn repository and [Hook Scripts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html). This hook scripts can checkout the code on every code change to your apache root. This is quite common an also used for automatic testing etc.